# Conditions for applying Case 3 of Master theorem

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

In Introduction to Algorithms, Lemma 4.4 of the proof of the master theorem goes like this.
$a\geq1$, $b>1$, $f$ is a nonnegative function defined on exact powers of b. The recurrence relation for $T$ is $T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)$ for $n=b^i$, $i>0$.

For the third case, we have $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_ba +\epsilon})$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$ and that $ af(n/b)\leq cf(n)$ for fixed $c<1$ and for all sufficiently large $n$. In this case, $T(n) =\Theta(f(n))$ since $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_ba +\epsilon})$.

I was wondering if the condition that $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_ba +\epsilon})$ is unnecessary since the regularity condition $ af(n/b)\leq cf(n)$ for all $n>n_0$ for fixed $c<1$ and for some $n_0$ implies that
$$
\begin{align*}
f(n)&\geq m\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^{\log_b(n/n_0)} \text{ where } m=\min_{1\leq x\leq n_0}{f(x)}\\&\ge\left(\frac{n}{n_0}\right)^{\log_b(a/c)}=\Theta(n^{\log_ba +\log_b(c^{-1})})=\Theta(n^{\log_ba +\epsilon}).
\end{align*}
$$
This will hold as long as $f(n)$ is non-zero. Hence $f(n)=\Omega(n^{\log_ba +\epsilon})$.
Therefore we merely need to add the condition that $f(n)$ is positive for all but finitely many values of $n$ for case 3. Am I correct about this?

Comment: You seem to be right. Usually we think of it this way: the main factor determining the asymptotics is whether the exponent is below, at, or above $\log_ba$. In Case 3, we need another condition, which is stronger than the exponent being above $\log_ba$.

Comment: It would have been more accurate for me to say that $f(n)$ is positive for the base cases, such that $m = min_{1\leq x\leq n_0} f(x)$ is positive. Since if m=0, $f(n)$ can be of any size (even if positive).

Comment: I've just realised that this question is precisely stated in exercise 4.6-3 that directly follows the chapter in CLRS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your sharp observation is completely correct.

---

To be compatible with the highly strict style shown at section 4.6, *Proof of the master theorem* of *Introduction to Algorithms*, here is the complete proposition and a slightly more rigorous proof. It seems that the proof in the question ignores the requirement that $f$ is defined only on exact powers of $b$.

(**Regularity implies lower-bounded by a greater-exponent polynomial.**) Let $a\geq1$, $b>1$ and $f$ be a nonnegative function defined on exact powers of $b$. Suppose $af(\frac nb)\leq cf(n)$ for some fixed $c<1$ and for all sufficiently large $n$. Furthermore, $0 < f(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Then $f(n) = \Omega(n^{log_ba +\epsilon})$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$.

**Proof**. There exists some $n_0>0$ such that $af(\frac nb)\leq cf(n)$ and $0 < f(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$. We can assume $n_0$ is an exact power of $b$ since, otherwise, we can replace $n_0$ by $b^{\lceil\log_b{n_0}\rceil}$.

Let $n\ge n_0$ be an exact power of $b$. So $n = n_0b^m$, where $m=\log_b\frac n{n_0}$ is an integer since both $n$ and $n_0$ are exact powers of $b$.
Applying $af(k/b)\leq cf(k)$ multiple times, we get

$$f(n) \ge \frac acf(\frac nb) \ge (\frac ac)^2f(\frac n{b^2})\ge \cdots \ge (\frac ac)^mf(\frac n{b^m})=(\frac ac)^mf(n_0)$$

Since
$$(\frac ac)^m=(\frac ac)^{\log_b\frac n{n_0}} =(\frac n{n_0})^{\log_b\frac ac}=(\frac n{n_0})^{\log_ba-\log_bc}=c_0n^{log_ba+\epsilon}$$
where $\epsilon=-\log_bc > 0$ and $c_0=(\frac1{n_0})^{log_ba +\epsilon}$ are two constants, we have

$$f(n) \ge c_0f(n_0)n^{log_ba +\epsilon}.$$
So,
$$f(n)=\Omega(n^{log_ba +\epsilon}).\quad \checkmark$$

---

What happens if $n$ is not necessarily an exact power of b?  The same result will hold if we replace $\frac nb$ by $\lfloor \frac nb\rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac nb\rceil$.  The following is a version when $\lfloor \frac nb\rfloor$ is used.

Let $a\ge1$, $b>1$ and $f$ be a nonnegative function defined on positive integers. Suppose $af(\lfloor \frac nb\rfloor)\leq cf(n)$ for some fixed $c<1$ and for all sufficiently large $n$. Furthermore, $0 < f(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Then $f(n) = \Omega(n^{log_ba +\epsilon})$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: If n is not an exact power of b, can we still prove the same result?

Comment: @jinge, if n is not an exact power of b, how should we define n/b such as 7/3? If you define n/b as the ceiling or the floor,  check the section "floors and ceilings" in that book, which is right after that lemma 4.4.

Comment: Yes, I know the section in that book. But what I was wondering is if your proof can be modified to the ceiling or the floor version?

Comment: @jinge, please check my updated answer.